# A question on linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ whose standard
matrix is 
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$ 
Does there exist a $3$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$,
$V$, and a linear transformation $S$ on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that
$S(\mathbf{v})=T(\mathbf{v})$ for all $\mathbf{v}\in V$ and $\left\Vert S(\mathbf{x})\right\Vert _{1}\le2$
for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{4}$ with $\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert _{1}=1$?

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Comment: Since $\|S(kx)\|_1 = \|kS(x)\|_1 = |k| \|S(x)\|_1$, I rather doubt it...

Comment: **Please** stop deleting questions.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(1,1,0,0),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,1)$ be a basis for your subspace. And let

$S = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right).$

Comment: @189: Mostly trial and error. It helped to notice that the subspace can't contain any of the standard basis vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$. I first tried $(1,1,0,0)$, $(0,1,1,0)$, $(0,0,1,1)$, but that didn't work. Then I saw that $(0,0,1,1)$ is probably good because I can get that $2\times2$ block of zeros at the right part of $S$.

Anyway, I understand your concern and I'd be happy myself to see a more systematic way of finding such a subspace.

Comment: @J.J. How would one go about proving that such a subspace doesn't exist (if in fact it didn't)?

Comment: @Weltschmerz: sadly I don't know.

Anyway, It seems to me that if we were using the Euclidean norm (which is induced by the inner product) instead of the Manhattan norm, the question might become easier. I suspect that then these subspaces are more tractable by looking at the eigenvectors of $T$. This is because if $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$, then we can extend it into an orthonormal basis for the whole space and define $S$ by $S(v_j) = T(v_j)$ for $j=1,\dots,k$ and $S(v) = 0$ for the other basis vectors. The norm of $S$ will be the norm of $T|V$.